# Chaining catkin workspaces on Windows

Tags: ros, catkin, win-ros, windows, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm been able to install ROS Groovy on Windows using the win_ros instructions (thanks to the win_ros guys for all the great work on that recently!).  I'm having trouble building my own catkin packages though.  How do you set up a chained catkin workspace on Windows?  Is this even a feature that is supported yet?

I have my main ROS workspace in c:\win_ros\src, c:\win_ros\devel, and c:\win_ros\build.  Everything built properly and the tutorial apps work.  I'm trying to create a new workspace for my catkinized packages in c:\my_ws in the same way I do on Linux but without success.  I've tried the following:

```
 c:\win_ros\devel\setup.bat
 cd\my_ws
 winros_init_workspace ./
 winros_init_build
 winros_make
```

Cmake is unable to find catkin and gives the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:47 (message):
  find_package(catkin) failed.  catkin was neither found in the workspace nor
  in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.  One reason may be that no ROS setup.sh was
  sourced before.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Executing nmake in the root build directory
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58599/chaining-catkin-workspaces-on-windows/) by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-19**:
Can you post the environment before and after you run `c:\win_ros\devel\setup.bat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nothing like finally posting a question to make you immediately figure it out.

From looking at the scripts at: https://github.com/ros-windows/win_ros/blob/groovy-devel/rosdeps/win_python_build_tools/scripts/winros_init_build.py  you can add an "underlay" when setting up the workspace:

```
winros_init_build -u c:/opt/ros/groovy/x86
```

That added a Cmake prefix variable to the config.cmake that winros_init_build makes that allowed it to find the main ros workspace and everything built correctly afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) with karma: 395 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're getting in early David. I am in the middle of updating everything and haven't made any public grunts about it yet.

Just by chance, I wrote up a wiki page on how I'm currently doing [overlays in windows](http://ros.org/wiki/win_ros/groovy/Msvc%20Overlays) on the wiki yesterday. Not sure if you chanced by that yet. Still, it should have worked by repeated sourcing, so I'll check into that. Might be some errors in the setup.bat.

This is all changing quite alot still, so you might want to subscribe to a few of those win_ros/groovy pages to get notified by email when things update.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2